# Chrome dev tools CSS source mapping doesn't work by default

Tags: css, sass, google-chrome-devtools, source-maps

Myself and my other developers are seeing an issue with Chrome dev tools not recognizing our CSS source maps immediately. Our minified CSS file and .map file are definitely being served and available to the dev tools, but we have to open Settings > Sources > Uncheck and Recheck "Enabled CSS source maps" to get the inspector to reference the actual _partial.scss files for styles. If we don't uncheck and recheck the source maps toggle, it just shows a direct line reference to the minified CSS file, which is not useful.

Has anyone encountered this issue before or know a better workaround for it? This is happening on the latest Chrome version and with several before it.

Comment: does anything change if you have "Auto-reload generated CSS" enabled?

Comment: No, I think that has to do with the browser responding to changes to the minified CSS. I have tried it both checked and unchecked without any difference.